# How is a GDP of an economy unaffected with reduction in GNP?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

I was reading my economics book and encountered with a paragraph which read:

"But GDP/NNP are now not considered as the best measures for the growth because countries having high extended debts are serviced through internal resources which tends to increase outflows and reduce GNP ' leaving GDP unaffected ' thus GNP/NNP are not seen as a correct way to judge the output of an economy"

Please answer the same by explaining the paragraph quoted.

PS : I know the answer is itself in the paragraph but I'm unable to understand  so I seek a good explanation of this paragraph with a good answer. Thanx in advance.

Comment: GNP is now usually called GNI (Gross National Income) so your book may be slightly behind the times

Answer (score 2):

GNP = GDP + Primary Income (PI).

So it is possible that PI falls, GDP stays constant, and GNP falls.

PI is often called "net income from abroad" (especially in older textbooks).

Examples of PI:

- A Canadian individual works for a US firm in the US for a month and is paid \$3,000. This \$3,000 is counted as credit (+) under Canada's PI and a debit (-) under US's PI.
- A French firm pays a German property-owner €1m to rent a piece of land in France (but which is owned by the German property-owner). This €1m is counted as credit (+) under Germany's PI and debit (-) under France's PI.
- A Japanese firm lends a Korean firm ¥1m. Each year, the Korean firm pays the Japanese firm ¥50,000 as an annual interest payment. This ¥50,000 is counted as credit (+) under Japan's PI and debit (-) under Korea's PI.

This last example is probably what your quoted text is referring to.